# Vue using canvas-datagrid shown warning message at console

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Everything is fine and shown as what i intended. But at console

```
> vue.js:2 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <canvas-datagrid> - did
> you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make
> sure to provide the "name" option.
> 
> found in
> 
> ---> <CGrid> at Vue/Components/cGrid.vue
>        <Root>
```

npm install --save-dev canvas-datagrid

cGrid.vue as below

```
<template>
    <canvas-datagrid :data.prop='d'></canvas-datagrid>
</template>

<script>
    import cGrid from "canvas-datagrid"
    export default {
        name: "c-grid",
        data() {
            return {
                d: [
                    { col1: 'abc' },
                    { col1: 'def' }
                ]
            }
        },
        components: {
            cGrid
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can i fix that warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the problem. Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['canvas-datagrid'];